# X button for exit dropdown menu only in css

Tags: html, css, button, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I managed to do the dropdown menu
the dropdown opens with the toggle hamburger button, once opened I managed to make an x-shaped button to exit, I would like clicking that button to close the dropdown and I would like to do it only with css, the problem is that it doesn't exit, I'm trying with :focus + but it doesn't work, any ideas

i try

'''

```
#close_menu_btn:focus + #form1 > div:nth-child(3) > header > nav.nav-box > ul {
    display: none !important;
}
```

'''

and

'''

```
#close_menu_btn:focus + f-cb {
    display: none !important;
}
```

'''

but doesn t work, any ideas?

```css
.label {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: none;
    color: #433F3F;
    float: right;
    width: 180px;
}

#toggle {
    display: none;
}
/* menu */

#close_menu_btn {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1205px) {

    #form1 > div:nth-child(3) > header > nav.nav-box > ul {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        min-width: 150px;
        box-shadow: 5px 16px 16px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #close_menu_btn {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 28px;
        line-height: 70px;
        color: grey;
        float: right;
        float: right;
    }

    .label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0 40px 0 0;
        font-size: 28px;
        line-height: 70px;
        color: grey;
        float: right;
        width: 26px;
        float: right;
    }

    #toggle:checked + .f-cb {
        display: block !important;
    }


    #close_menu_btn:focus + #form1 > div:nth-child(3) > header > nav.nav-box > ul {
        display: none !important;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {

    .label {
        margin: 0 40px 0 0;
        font-size: 28px;
        line-height: 70px;
        color: grey;
        float: right;
        width: 26px;
        float: right;
    }

    #close_menu_btn {
        font-size: 28px;
        line-height: 70px;
        color: grey;
        float: right;
        float: right;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-box">
         <label class="label" for="toggle">
          &#9776;
         </label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
            <ul class="f-cb">
              <li id="close_btn_container">
               <button id="close_menu_btn" class="cursor_pointer" type="button">
                             &#10006;
               </button>
               </li>
         <!--my menu other li -->
            </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Showing your menu is based on the checkbox input being checked. Checking that input happens by clicking the label, which will _toggle_ the current state of the checkbox. So, don't try to mess around with :focus - but just make your close button a label for that same checkbox input as well ...